# It says "Running watch task" and "Waiting....", but, watch never appears to run UNLESS the file I edited was the Gruntfile itself

Tags: apache, laravel-4, gruntjs, grunt-contrib-watch

I'm having trouble using Grunt in a new Laravel project. At the moment I can't seem to configure/run grunt-contrib-watch correctly.

Directory Structure:

```
|-- app
|-- node_modules
|-- Gruntfile.js
|-- package.json
|-- public
|---- bower_components
|---- css
|------ dist
|------ header.css
|---- js
|------ dist
|------ app.js
```

And I have my Laravel project setup to find View files from the public folder in app/config/view.php:

```
'paths' => array(__DIR__.'/../../public'),
```

Laravel is installed and Apache is setup, and I'm trying to test a reload of changes using Grunt. Whenever I run grunt, it says "Running watch task" and "Waiting....", however, watch never appears to run UNLESS the file I edited was the Gruntfile itself.

Here's my Gruntfile:

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {

    /* Config for Project */
    grunt.initConfig({

        pkg: grunt.file.readJSON('package.json'),

        cssmin: {
            dist: {
                src: 'public/css/*.css',
                dest: 'css/dist/main.min.css'
            }
        },

        uglify: {
            dist: {
                src: ['public/js/*.js'],
                dest: 'js/dist/app.min.js'
            }
        },

        watch: {
            js: {
                files: ['**/*.js'],
                tasks: ['uglify'],
                options: {
                    reload: true
                }
            },
            css: {
                files: ['**/*.css'],
                tasks: ['cssmin'],
                options: {
                    reload: true
                }
            }
        }

    });

    grunt.event.on('watch', function(action, filepath, target) {
        grunt.log.writeln(target + ': ' + filepath + ' has ' + action);
    });

    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-watch');
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-cssmin');
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-less');
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-uglify');


    // grunt.registerTask('buildcss',  ['sass', 'cssc', 'cssmin']);
    grunt.registerTask('default', ['watch',]);
};
```

Does anyone have an idea what I mis-configured / why watch isn't running?

Answer (score 0):

your grunt:watch task is doing exactly what you are telling it to do. Here's the task commented

```
    watch: {
        // this means, whenever a .js file changes, run "grunt uglify"
        js: {
            files: ['**/*.js'],
            tasks: ['uglify'],
            options: {
                reload: true
            }
        },
        // this means, whenever a .css file changes, run "grunt cssmin"
        css: {
            files: ['**/*.css'],
            tasks: ['cssmin'],
            options: {
                reload: true
            }
        }
    }
```

There is no less compilation because you're not telling your `grunt:watch` to compile the less files when they change...

you'll need another plugin to compile your less files, check https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-less, configure that plugin task and then add a new `grunt:watch` directive, that should look something like:

```
        less: {
            // this means, whenever a .less file changes, run 'grunt less'
            files: ['**/*.less'],
            tasks: ['less']
        }
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Thank you for answering. :)
And right, that's at least what I want the tasks to do.

It's watch running at all that I'm having trouble with: watch only seems to run when I change the Gruntfile, but it does not when I change any files in public/css or public/js.

Comment: hmmm then that's weird.. there's nothing wrong on your config, I see you tried to debug it using `reload: true` and adding capturing the event on `watch`.. try to remove all that and test your gruntfile pointing to one single js file, something like `files: ['path/simple.js']` and run `grunt -d -v watch` it will give us more information about the task